# CentOS 6.x (6.10) to CentOS 7.x

Tags: centos, centos7, centos6, centos6.5

I looked at a lot of resources, but I couldn't find any useful information. Either repos are broken or prepug problems...

> I/O warning : failed to load external entity
>   "/usr/share/openscap/xsl/security-guide.xsl" compilation error: file
>   /usr/share/preupgrade/xsl/preup.xsl line 40 element import xsl:import
>   : unable to load /usr/share/openscap/xsl/security-guide.xsl I/O
>   warning : failed to load external entity
>   "/usr/share/openscap/xsl/oval-report.xsl" compilation error: file
>   /usr/share/preupgrade/xsl/preup.xsl line 41 element import xsl:import
>   : unable to load /usr/share/openscap/xsl/oval-report.xsl I/O warning :
>   failed to load external entity
>   "/usr/share/openscap/xsl/sce-report.xsl" compilation error: file
>   /usr/share/preupgrade/xsl/preup.xsl line 42 element import xsl:import
>   : unable to load /usr/share/openscap/xsl/sce-report.xsl OpenSCAP
>   Error:: Could not parse XSLT file
>   '/usr/share/preupgrade/xsl/preup.xsl' [oscapxml.c:416] Unable to open
>   file /root/preupgrade/result.html Usage: preupg [options]
>
> preupg: error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '/root/preupgrade/result.html' [root@localhost upgrade]# yum
>   localinstall redhat-upgrade-tool-0.7.22-3.el6.centos.noarch.rpm Failed
>   to set locale, defaulting to C Loaded plugins: fastestmirror Setting
>   up Local Package Process Examining
>   redhat-upgrade-tool-0.7.22-3.el6.centos.noarch.rpm:
>   1:redhat-upgrade-tool-0.7.22-3.el6.centos.noarch
>   redhat-upgrade-tool-0.7.22-3.el6.centos.noarch.rpm: does not update
>   installed package. Nothing to do [root@localhost upgrade]# rpm
>   --import http://ftp.plusline.de/centos/7.0.1406/os/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
>   curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found error:
>   http://ftp.plusline.de/centos/7.0.1406/os/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7:
>   import read failed(2). [root@localhost upgrade]#  [root@localhost
>   upgrade]# rpm --import
>   http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
>   curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found error:
>   http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7:
>   import read failed(2).

Comment: Remove openscap and install https://buildlogs.centos.org/centos/6/upg/x86_64/Packages/openscap-1.0.8-1.0.1.el6.centos.x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, the upgrade path from Centos 6.x to 7.x has been broken since shortly after 7.x was released, with no fixes to preupg in sight - and at this point, it seems unlikely the official route will work. Further, I don't know of ANY unofficial route that is proven to work well, either.

The only real and trusted upgrade path from Centos 6x to 7x is to install 7 onto fresh hardware/vm and migrate services over.

This surprises folk coming from other distros where, whilst not being trivial, it is usually achievable to upgrade between major versions in-situ, but this does not seem to be the Centos way.